# Hide re.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:698) [coreserver.jar:?]

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

HybrisContextFactory$ApplicationContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:263) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getApplicationInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:87) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.createCoreApplicationContext(AbstractTenant.java:726) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:765) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:698) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.assureTenantStarted(Registry.java:658) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateTenant(Registry.java:719) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:566) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateMasterTenant(Registry.java:626) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.ClientExecuter.execute(ClientExecuter.java:43) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.execute(Loader.java:142) [ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:118) [ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultProductInterestRelationConverter' defined in class path resource [customerinterestsfacades-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'productInterestRelationPopulator' while setting bean property 'populators' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productInterestRelationPopulator' defined in class path resource [customerinterestsfacades-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'de.hybris.platform.acceleratorfacades.futurestock.impl.DefaultFutureStockFacade' to required type 'de.hybris.platform.customerinterestsfacades.futurestoc

Comment: Which Hybris version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to login with the **mani1** user please run the following impex:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Employee;uid[unique=true];backOfficeLoginDisabled;
;mani1;false;
```

Above impex sets the **backOfficeLoginDisabled** to false allowing **mani1** user to be able to login.

Another option would be assigning to the user the OOTB(Out Of The Box) **backofficeadmingroup**.

Answer (score 0):

Once we have a stable production setup, ideally we do not perform Initialization. To avoid any accident, it's good to block the Initialization option from HAC for all the users.

Refer [how-to-block-system-initialization-in-production](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/02/block-prevent-system-initialization-production-hybris.html), where you can find a few possible options.

If you are using Hybris V 6.1 or any higher version and want to give HAC tab specific access using user groups/roles then all you have to do is assign a specific user group to your user and you are done. There are predefined user groups like ROLE_HAC_PLATFORM_INITIALIZATION, ROLE_HAC_PLATFORM_UPDATE and many more. You can find a full list of HAC roles and more details [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/6.1.0.0/en-US/5bfac051a46e4c17ac79c738ff739270.html#).

Comment: #hybrishelp  thnks for the help. but in this situation i want a user who can do everything as admin except intialization

Comment: i add every group to this user except HAC_PLATFORM_INITIALIZATION ,but i only getting the only console

Comment: You can try assigning all other roles to that user but not system initialization. I haven't tried it personally but seems possible. Also, think of the other option given in the above-mentioned article.

Answer (score 0):

sanker

You can fix it by assigning OOB user-group `hac_platform_initialization` to only expected non-admin employee users in your system.

Something like...

```
INSERT_UPDATE Employee;UID[unique=true];groups(uid)  
                      ;mani1           ;hac_platform_initialization;
```

This way you can allow the function to only limited set of users.

Hope it helps. Thanks!